# The matrix derivative of Hadamard product $\partial/\partial X tr(A\odot X)$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, hadamard-product, scalar-fields

I'm looking for the closed solution $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial X} tr(A\odot X)$. What I got is the diagonal matrix with entries $A_{ii}$. Is that correct?

And one more question. What would be $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial X} tr((A\odot X)^T (A\odot X))$? When calculating this, do I simply use the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the trace with a Frobenius product, and recall that the Frobenius (:) and Hadamard ($\circ$) products are mutually commutative, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{
C:A\circ B & =A\circ B:C \cr &= A:B\circ C \cr &= A:C\circ B \cr\cr
}$$

Then the first function, differential, and gradient are
$$\eqalign{
 f &= {\rm tr}(A\circ X) = I:A\circ X = I\circ A:X \cr\cr
df &= I\circ A:dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= I\circ A = {\rm Diag}(A) \cr\cr
}$$
Applying this same technique to your second function yields
$$\eqalign{
 f &= A\circ X:A\circ X \cr\cr
df &= 2\,A\circ X:A\circ dX \cr &=  2\,A\circ A\circ X:dX  \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= 2\,A\circ A\circ X \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: I got this answer but in a kind of naive way. Thanks for your technique.

Comment: but where can I get the general formula for your differential calculations?

Comment: can I find the formula in 'matrix cookbook'?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that most college students do not know the concept of derivative (or differential) of a function ? It is as if Bolt runs 100 meters in wooden clogs...

@  julypraise , if you ask for a formula in matrix cookbook, then certainly, you did not understand the Hans' answer.

Let $f:X\in M_n\rightarrow tr(A\circ X),g:X\in M_n\rightarrow tr((A\circ X)^T(A\circ X))$. Since $f$ is linear, $Df_X:H\in M_n\rightarrow tr(A\circ H)$. On the other hand, $Dg_X:H\rightarrow  2tr((A\circ H)^T(A\circ X))$.